# JDBC connection not available

Tags: jdbc, websphere, database-connection, portlet, jdbctemplate

I appreciate everybody giving solutions/suggestions to my post.

**Environment:** Portlet, Ibm Websphere, Java.

**Scenario:** In the portal application, whenever I hit a menu item(or portlet) the server often goes down hardly in an hour. Doesn't matter whether I remain in the same menu item(or portlet) or go to another menu item(or portlet). As a result after server down, we used to get **backside connection cannot be established.**

Connection pool size in server = 50.

**In the application:** **Database calls within a for has a loop of 900 iterations.** Checking the log I came to know for the first 50 iterations, the operation is well carried out within seconds. But from the 51st iteration, there happens a connection timeout stating JDBC connection not available and thereafter for every iteration it takes 3 minutes(keeps waiting for database connection but not getting it).

**Sample code:**

```
listSize = 900;
for(int i=0; i < listSize; i++){

    // database query for setting a status message.

}
```

We suspected that this might be due to open database connections. So connections are not available for 51st iteration after reaching the pool size of 50. But in the application there is **spring's jdbcTemplate** used which should automatically open/close connections.

**Question(s):**

1. What could be the exact cause of this scenario? Because of using the DB calls inside for loop causes the performance issue and not giving the connections to threads from 51st iteration?
2. If the spring automatically closes the connections, then why it is not giving the connection to new iterations from the 51st?
3. Is the for loop iterations are faster than spring's connection closure? So that first 50 threads iterating and not from 51st?

Comment: Asking more than one question is usually an indication that your question is too broad, second of all, you need to show some code surrounding your use of connections. Usually **your code** must close connections so that they are returned to the connection pool in a timely fashion.

Comment: if you want detailed answers, you'll have to post more detailed code.  The only code example you have posted so far is a for loop with nothing in it...

Answer (score 0):

When you said "Connection pool size in server = 50", I assuming you mean max connections is set to 50.  As you suspected, the behavior you're seeing indicates that the free pool is being exhausted by connection requests.  Based on your "for" loop, the first 50 connection requests caused by queries are successful but since the connections are not being returned to the free pool, the 51st connection request is going to the waiter pool and eventually timing out after 180 seconds.  You're correct that the Spring jdbcTemplate configuration is supposed to close() the connection when complete, thus returning the connection to the pool, so you will need to investigate why that is happening.  Turing on WebSphere Application server tracing with tracespec of rra=all might give you some insight, see IBM Knowledge Center topic to [turn on trace](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.5.0/trouble/pd_intr_logs.dita).  Additional trace can be obtained with WAS.j2c=all, but it's going to be verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article - [Default behavior of managed connections in WebSphere Application Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0506_johnsen/0506_johnsen.html). You are probably using sharable connections and local transactions. Try to configure resource reference used by your application and set connections to `unsharable`. Put something like this in your `web.xml`, and use `java:comp/env/jdbc/datasourceRef` in your Spring configuration.

```
<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/datasourceRef</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Application</res-auth>
<res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```